# XAMPP PHP date function time is different from local machine time

Tags: php, xampp

My computer local time is `12-03-2013 4:30pm`.

My XAMPP date function prints the time as `12-03-2013 10:49:56`.

How can I set the XAMPP server time to display the system time?

Comment: What are you using to display the time?

Comment: just php date function. The date function is displaying time: Mar 12, 2013 @ 11:31 (1363087870) where as my system it is Mar 12, 2013 @ 04:31.

Comment: Then it's a timezone issue. It wasn't clear from your initial question where you said it's a difference between 4:30 and 10:49.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Go to `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`, or your custom path where `php.ini` is, open it.

Look for the following: `date.timezone = "Europe/Warsaw"`. Probably You have different value than my `Europe/Warsaw`. So search just string: `date.timezone`.

Change value `Europe/Warsaw` to the proper value, for example `date.timezone = "Asia/Kolkata"`

If someone's looking for his location, check valid values http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Don't forget to restart your XAMPP.

Comment: Maybe him timezone is +/- 6:15 ;) If not timezone is wrong, so what?
Seriously, I suspect that he gave this hour approximately.
Edit: @Pekka 웃  why u delete your comment?

Comment: Thanks. In my case, i changed to date.timezone = Asia/Kolkata.

Comment: So for Philippines - date.timezone = Asia/Philippines

Answer (score 4):

At your XAMPP you can change the php.ini and search

```
date.timezone
```

and change it to your prefer timezone

```
date.timezone = Asia/Jakarta
```

That's for XAMPP. And if you can't change the web server time at your remote server, try put this date_default_timezone_set() function at your php. Like this :

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

For others who are confused on what timezone (date.timezone) they should use (just like me a while ago), please refer to this manual from PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the timezone accordingly

```
date-default-timezone-set('GMT');
```

More read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

But I would suggest use mysql `now()` or `curdate()` to take the server time.

Comment: Look at the time difference he's describing - how would that be caused by time zones?

Answer (score 0):

No need to change xampp's `php.ini` file. Add `date_default_timezone_set()` function before taking the current time.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Use this way because if you are hosting your website the the time will be displayed according to the host server. So use this method to get away from future errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use

> date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

for your PHP application. It gives you the same time on all servers.

I have a CI application and its host to the server so apache is following other timezones and in local its follows differently.

I add date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); in my config.php file and working like champ.